# how to create a mask for a sprite or for a texture in libgdx

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, masking, image-masking

I am developing on libgdx for android and the thing is that I've used masks for my sprites before (not in libgdx) to set the surrounding of my sprites to be transparent so when I draw them to the screen they show the background and not a white rectangle, but I don't seem to find any way to do this in libdgx, how do you guys go about crating masks for your 2d sprites? Do I have to use OpenGL cause I don't know much about it if so can you tell me how? and also can I do it on a texture?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just use PNG images for sprites with transparent pixels in them. These PNG images are packed to bigger PNG texture file with either Texture Packer or using Libgdx to make the texture.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mesh like this http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MeshColorTexture